# Secondary voltage, lagging load power factor (transformers)

Tags: transformer, electromagnetic, core

Theoretically in transformers, will the secondary voltage increase or decrease (with increasing load current and a lagging load power factor) and why?

Comment: It depends how you are driving the transformer's primary winding or, put another way, if the voltage source has a complex impedance, depending on the load, the voltage could rise or fall.

Comment: Primary winding driven by simple AC sinusoidal voltage

Comment: Are you happy with the answer I gave? Any doubts or further comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Primary winding driven by simple AC sinusoidal voltage

Assuming there are no tuned resonances occuring (due to distributed winding capacitances), if you apply a lagging load (inductive) to the secondary, you can expect the secondary voltage to drop. It might drop a really small amount if the inductive load is many henries or it might drop a lot if the load takes lots of current.

The equivalent circuit of a transformer should confirm my answer: -

[image]